# Reference for Dieudonné modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I am looking for a basic (understandable) reference on Dieudonné modules.

Specifically, I am trying to understand how it relates to certain cohomology groups of abelian varieties.

Comment: There are a number of different technical frameworks that work for different purposes.  You should give some more details of the context in which you are working.

Comment: There's a decent explanation in Waterhouse's *Abelian varieties over finite fields*.

Comment: The usual place is [Katz](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nmk/old/CrCohDModJacSum.pdf) which is still very readable.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the list of references in the following [syllabus](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/viehmann/sempdiv/pdiv_programm.pdf) (Eva Viehmann's seminar on p-divisible groups).

Comment: The link seems to be broken.