# Dieudonné modules -reference request

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry

I need a reference to start learning about Dieudonn\'e modules, and their application to the arithmetic of abelian varieities. I know that this is a  copy of [Reference for Dieudonné modules](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96507/reference-for-dieudonn%C3%A9-modules), but... the link proposed there are broken :'(
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does http://www.math.harvard.edu/~chaoli/doc/Dieudonne.html help you (Chao Li's lecture notes)?

Comment: I think it does, and I can also follows the references if I need more!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The comment at the top about a link on another MO page being broken applies to the link in this answer too. A new working link is http://www.math.columbia.edu/~chaoli/docs/Dieudonne.html until that one is broken...